# How do I move the elements of an unordered list to the left?

Tags: html, css

[picture of my calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfOfY.png)

As you can see, the blue blocks don't align with the weekday names. I'm fairly new to HTML, so any links or solutions would greatly help. I'm trying to move the blue blocks to the left but I don't know how to do that in HTML or CSS. Thank you.

Also, if anyone knows how to make the list's END line up with each other, that would be great. I've just been playing around with the width but none of them match.

Here is the code for my calendar's blocks:

```
  <ul class="days">
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
  <li><span class="active"></span></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.days li .active {
    padding: 40px;
    background: #b3ecff;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

i think the problem is for the default **ul** and **ol** elements margin and padding.

```
.days {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```